# Target ng-if outside controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a feedback feature on my app,

```
#feedback
  %h3.button
    %a{"ui-sref" => ".feedback", "ng-click" => "feedbackActive=!feedbackActive;"}
      Feedback
  #feedback-container{"ng-if" => "feedbackActive"}
    %div{"ui-view" => "feedback"}
```

The `#feedback-container` has a `ng-if` so that the content is only loaded when needed. The `%a` has a ng-click that toggles between true/false for the the `feedbackActive` state.

This works fine. Howoever in my ui-view I load a template. In that template is a send button that has a `send()` function linked to the `feedbackCtrl`,

```
$scope.send = function(){
  console.log ('send')
  console.log ($scope.feedbackForm)

  createFeedback.create({
    name:      $scope.feedbackForm.name,
    feedback:  $scope.feedbackForm.feedback
  })
  $scope.feedbackActive = false;
}
```

It runs the code fine, but doesn't give the `feedbackActive` the false value so nothing happens.

How do remove toggle the `ng-if` from outside the controller?

Comment: Start using controllerAs it should sole this problem.

Comment: can you provide your proper conditional code .

Comment: @Viplock How do you mean? This is all the code I have for the feedback function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic scoping issue. Your controller's scope is a child of the scope of the `ng-if` directive. One option is to use `$scope.$parent` to set the variable on the parent scope.

```
$scope.send = function(){
  console.log ('send')
  console.log ($scope.feedbackForm)

  createFeedback.create({
    name:      $scope.feedbackForm.name,
    feedback:  $scope.feedbackForm.feedback
  })
  $scope.$parent.feedbackActive = false;
}
```

The other option is to take advantage of prototypical inheritance. In the parent controller, initialize an object.

```
$scope.x = {}; //parent scope
```

In the view controller, set properties on the inherited object.

```
$scope.x.feedbackActive = false; //child scope
```

And of course in your HTML

```
<feedback-container ng-if="x.feedbackActive">
```